# docker build error when building miniconda env on macbook pro m1 arm64

Tags: docker, arm64, miniconda

im trying to dockerize a ML API service and i have my dependencies in a environment.yml file.

the docker file i have written is the following:

```
FROM --platform=arm64 continuumio/miniconda3:latest

# Set up Conda and create a virtual environment
RUN conda update -n base -c defaults conda

# Create a directory to hold the environment file
WORKDIR /code

# Copy the environment.yml file into the image
COPY ./environment.yml /code/environment.yml

# Create Conda environment based on the environment.yml file
RUN conda env create -f /code/environment.yml

# Activate the Conda environment
SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "your_environment_name", "/bin/bash", "-c"]

# Set the working directory to /code
WORKDIR /code

# Copy your source code and model files
COPY ./src ./src/
COPY ./model ./model/

# Set the default command to run your Python script
CMD ["python", "./src/main.py"]
```

and here is my environement.yml file:

```
name: ELMAml
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - _tflow_select=2.2.0=eigen
  - abseil-cpp=20211102.0=hc377ac9_0
  - absl-py=1.4.0=py311hca03da5_0
  - aiohttp=3.8.5=py311h80987f9_0
  - aiosignal=1.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - annotated-types=0.6.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - anyio=3.7.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - arrow-cpp=11.0.0=he3f21e0_2
  - astunparse=1.6.3=py_0
  - async-timeout=4.0.2=py311hca03da5_0
  - attrs=23.1.0=py311hca03da5_0
  - aws-c-common=0.6.8=h80987f9_1
  - aws-c-event-stream=0.1.6=h313beb8_6
  - aws-checksums=0.1.11=h80987f9_2
  - aws-sdk-cpp=1.8.185=h4a942e0_0
  - blas=1.0=openblas
  - blinker=1.6.2=py311hca03da5_0
  - boost-cpp=1.73.0=h1a28f6b_12
  - bottleneck=1.3.5=py311ha0d4635_0
  - brotli=1.0.9=h1a28f6b_7
  - brotli-bin=1.0.9=h1a28f6b_7
  - brotli-python=1.0.9=py311h313beb8_7
  - bzip2=1.0.8=h620ffc9_4
  - c-ares=1.19.1=h80987f9_0
  - ca-certificates=2023.11.17=hf0a4a13_0
  - cachetools=4.2.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - certifi=2023.11.17=py311hca03da5_0
  - cffi=1.16.0=py311h80987f9_0
  - charset-normalizer=2.0.4=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - click=8.1.7=py311hca03da5_0
  - cryptography=41.0.3=py311h3c57c4d_0
  - datasets=2.12.0=py311hca03da5_0
  - dill=0.3.6=py311hca03da5_0
  - exceptiongroup=1.2.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - fastapi=0.105.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - filelock=3.13.1=py311hca03da5_0
  - flatbuffers=2.0.0=hc377ac9_0
  - frozenlist=1.4.0=py311h80987f9_0
  - fsspec=2023.9.2=py311hca03da5_0
  - gast=0.4.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - gflags=2.2.2=hc377ac9_0
  - giflib=5.2.1=h80987f9_3
  - git-lfs=2.13.3=hca03da5_0
  - glog=0.5.0=hc377ac9_0
  - gmp=6.2.1=hc377ac9_3
  - gmpy2=2.1.2=py311h40f64dc_0
  - google-auth=2.22.0=py311hca03da5_0
  - google-auth-oauthlib=0.5.2=py311hca03da5_0
  - google-pasta=0.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - grpc-cpp=1.48.2=h877324c_0
  - grpcio=1.48.2=py311h877324c_0
  - gtest=1.14.0=h48ca7d4_0
  - h11=0.14.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - h5py=3.9.0=py311hba6ad2f_0
  - hdf5=1.12.1=h160e8cb_2
  - huggingface_hub=0.17.3=py311hca03da5_0
  - icu=68.1=hc377ac9_0
  - idna=3.4=py311hca03da5_0
  - importlib-metadata=6.0.0=py311hca03da5_0
  - jinja2=3.1.2=py311hca03da5_0
  - joblib=1.3.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jpeg=9e=h80987f9_1
  - keras=2.12.0=py311hca03da5_0
  - keras-preprocessing=1.1.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - krb5=1.20.1=h8380606_1
  - libboost=1.73.0=h49e8a49_12
  - libbrotlicommon=1.0.9=h1a28f6b_7
  - libbrotlidec=1.0.9=h1a28f6b_7
  - libbrotlienc=1.0.9=h1a28f6b_7
  - libcurl=8.2.1=h0f1d93c_0
  - libcxx=16.0.6=h4653b0c_0
  - libedit=3.1.20221030=h80987f9_0
  - libev=4.33=h1a28f6b_1
  - libevent=2.1.12=hf27765b_0
  - libffi=3.4.4=hca03da5_0
  - libgfortran=5.0.0=11_3_0_hca03da5_28
  - libgfortran5=11.3.0=h009349e_28
  - libiconv=1.16=h1a28f6b_2
  - libnghttp2=1.52.0=h10c0552_1
  - libopenblas=0.3.21=h269037a_0
  - libpng=1.6.39=h80987f9_0
  - libprotobuf=3.20.3=h514c7bf_0
  - libsqlite=3.44.2=h091b4b1_0
  - libssh2=1.10.0=h449679c_2
  - libthrift=0.15.0=h169de6a_2
  - libuv=1.44.2=h80987f9_0
  - libzlib=1.2.13=h53f4e23_5
  - llvm-openmp=17.0.6=hcd81f8e_0
  - lz4-c=1.9.4=h313beb8_0
  - markdown=3.4.1=py311hca03da5_0
  - markupsafe=2.1.1=py311h80987f9_0
  - mpc=1.1.0=h8c48613_1
  - mpfr=4.0.2=h695f6f0_1
  - mpmath=1.3.0=py311hca03da5_0
  - multidict=6.0.2=py311h80987f9_0
  - multiprocess=0.70.14=py311hca03da5_0
  - ncurses=6.4=h313beb8_0
  - networkx=3.1=py311hca03da5_0
  - ninja=1.10.2=hca03da5_5
  - ninja-base=1.10.2=h525c30c_5
  - nltk=3.8.1=py311hca03da5_0
  - numexpr=2.8.7=py311h6dc990b_0
  - numpy=1.23.5=py311hb2c0538_0
  - numpy-base=1.23.5=py311h9eb1c70_0
  - oauthlib=3.2.2=py311hca03da5_0
  - openssl=1.1.1w=h1a28f6b_0
  - opt_einsum=3.3.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - orc=1.7.4=hdca1487_1
  - packaging=23.1=py311hca03da5_0
  - pandas=2.1.4=py311h7aedaa7_0
  - pip=23.3=py311hca03da5_0
  - protobuf=3.20.3=py311h313beb8_0
  - pyarrow=11.0.0=py311h7575258_1
  - pyasn1=0.4.8=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pyasn1-modules=0.2.8=py_0
  - pycparser=2.21=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pydantic=2.5.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pydantic-core=2.14.5=py311h94f323b_0
  - pyjwt=2.4.0=py311hca03da5_0
  - pyopenssl=23.2.0=py311hca03da5_0
  - pysocks=1.7.1=py311hca03da5_0
  - python=3.11.0=hf452327_1_cpython
  - python-dateutil=2.8.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - python-flatbuffers=2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - python-tzdata=2023.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - python-xxhash=2.0.2=py311h80987f9_1
  - python_abi=3.11=4_cp311
  - pytorch=2.1.0=gpu_mps_py311hf322ab5_100
  - pytz=2023.3.post1=py311hca03da5_0
  - pyyaml=6.0.1=py311h80987f9_0
  - re2=2022.04.01=hc377ac9_0
  - readline=8.2=h1a28f6b_0
  - regex=2023.10.3=py311h80987f9_0
  - requests=2.31.0=py311hca03da5_0
  - requests-oauthlib=1.3.0=py_0
  - responses=0.13.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - rsa=4.7.2=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - safetensors=0.4.0=py311h62f922a_0
  - scikit-learn=1.3.2=py311ha25ca4d_2
  - scipy=1.11.3=py311hc76d9b0_0
  - sentencepiece=0.1.99=py311h48ca7d4_0
  - setuptools=68.0.0=py311hca03da5_0
  - six=1.16.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - sleef=3.5.1=h80987f9_2
  - snappy=1.1.9=hc377ac9_0
  - sniffio=1.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - sqlite=3.41.2=h80987f9_0
  - starlette=0.27.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - sympy=1.11.1=py311hca03da5_0
  - tensorboard=2.12.1=py311hca03da5_0
  - tensorboard-data-server=0.7.0=py311ha6e5c4f_0
  - tensorboard-plugin-wit=1.8.1=py311hca03da5_0
  - tensorflow=2.12.0=eigen_py311h689d69b_0
  - tensorflow-base=2.12.0=eigen_py311h0a52ebb_0
  - tensorflow-estimator=2.12.0=py311hca03da5_0
  - termcolor=2.1.0=py311hca03da5_0
  - threadpoolctl=3.2.0=pyha21a80b_0
  - tk=8.6.12=hb8d0fd4_0
  - tokenizers=0.13.2=py311h3dd52b7_1
  - tqdm=4.65.0=py311hb6e6a13_0
  - transformers=4.32.1=py311hca03da5_0
  - typing-extensions=4.9.0=hd8ed1ab_0
  - typing_extensions=4.9.0=pyha770c72_0
  - tzdata=2023c=h04d1e81_0
  - urllib3=1.26.18=py311hca03da5_0
  - utf8proc=2.6.1=h1a28f6b_0
  - uvicorn=0.24.0.post1=py311h267d04e_0
  - werkzeug=2.2.3=py311hca03da5_0
  - wheel=0.35.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - wrapt=1.14.1=py311h80987f9_0
  - xxhash=0.8.0=h1a28f6b_3
  - xz=5.4.2=h80987f9_0
  - yaml=0.2.5=h1a28f6b_0
  - yarl=1.8.1=py311h80987f9_0
  - zipp=3.11.0=py311hca03da5_0
  - zlib=1.2.13=h53f4e23_5
  - zstd=1.5.5=hd90d995_0
prefix: /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/ELMAml
```

when i try a build with the `docker build -t elma-ml-api:1.0 .`  command, i have the following error occuring:

```
+] Building 27.0s (9/12)                                                                                                         docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load build definition from dockerfile                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 774B                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring context: 738B                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/continuumio/miniconda3:latest                                                                          1.3s
 => [1/8] FROM docker.io/continuumio/miniconda3:latest@sha256:5ee0ed861bce8f67acb0a3e8a416891781db54302d93bf20a3c6301d7683d7b9                    8.8s
 => => resolve docker.io/continuumio/miniconda3:latest@sha256:5ee0ed861bce8f67acb0a3e8a416891781db54302d93bf20a3c6301d7683d7b9                    0.0s
 => => sha256:7bb145af9f334ae1d3fbbbc1ec7b1740e8889b7756f603d3c269d2459547f193 868B / 868B                                                        0.0s
 => => sha256:af7e10700ef8024c2979defa0180c44a6422aa523ce5fa69533c69ccdf7ae250 4.61kB / 4.61kB                                                    0.0s
 => => sha256:6e498137f0ed1053c364a5c8a688616b4abee72496a0b97cc71ea5e603565070 30.06MB / 30.06MB                                                  0.6s
 => => sha256:ba059ebc311289dbc91295136fcb2cbaaa7cec59e431de1b04945574c3cabce4 50.14MB / 50.14MB                                                  1.8s
 => => sha256:d8cab84b5c97f59bc994d6360151629eec702fe47b8d594286543300cdcf7c6c 83.24MB / 83.24MB                                                  2.1s
 => => sha256:5ee0ed861bce8f67acb0a3e8a416891781db54302d93bf20a3c6301d7683d7b9 3.11kB / 3.11kB                                                    0.0s
 => => extracting sha256:6e498137f0ed1053c364a5c8a688616b4abee72496a0b97cc71ea5e603565070                                                         2.5s
 => => extracting sha256:ba059ebc311289dbc91295136fcb2cbaaa7cec59e431de1b04945574c3cabce4                                                         1.7s
 => => extracting sha256:d8cab84b5c97f59bc994d6360151629eec702fe47b8d594286543300cdcf7c6c                                                         3.4s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                 3.4s
 => => transferring context: 541.75MB                                                                                                             3.4s
 => [2/8] RUN conda update -n base -c defaults conda                                                                                              4.2s
 => [3/8] WORKDIR /code                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [4/8] COPY ./environment.yml /code/environment.yml                                                                                            0.0s
 => ERROR [5/8] RUN conda env create -f /code/environment.yml                                                                                    12.6s
------
 > [5/8] RUN conda env create -f /code/environment.yml:
0.639 Channels:
0.639  - conda-forge
0.639  - defaults
0.639 Platform: linux-aarch64
0.639 Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
11.63 Solving environment: ...working... failed
12.45 
12.45 PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
12.45 
12.45   - abseil-cpp==20211102.0=hc377ac9_0
12.45   - absl-py==1.4.0=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - aiohttp==3.8.5=py311h80987f9_0
12.45   - arrow-cpp==11.0.0=he3f21e0_2
12.45   - async-timeout==4.0.2=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - attrs==23.1.0=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - aws-c-common==0.6.8=h80987f9_1
12.45   - aws-c-event-stream==0.1.6=h313beb8_6
12.45   - aws-checksums==0.1.11=h80987f9_2
12.45   - aws-sdk-cpp==1.8.185=h4a942e0_0
12.45   - blinker==1.6.2=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - boost-cpp==1.73.0=h1a28f6b_12
12.45   - bottleneck==1.3.5=py311ha0d4635_0
12.45   - brotli==1.0.9=h1a28f6b_7
12.45   - brotli-bin==1.0.9=h1a28f6b_7
12.45   - brotli-python==1.0.9=py311h313beb8_7
12.45   - bzip2==1.0.8=h620ffc9_4
12.45   - c-ares==1.19.1=h80987f9_0
12.45   - ca-certificates==2023.11.17=hf0a4a13_0
12.45   - certifi==2023.11.17=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - cffi==1.16.0=py311h80987f9_0
12.45   - click==8.1.7=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - cryptography==41.0.3=py311h3c57c4d_0
12.45   - datasets==2.12.0=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - dill==0.3.6=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - filelock==3.13.1=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - flatbuffers==2.0.0=hc377ac9_0
12.45   - frozenlist==1.4.0=py311h80987f9_0
12.45   - fsspec==2023.9.2=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - gflags==2.2.2=hc377ac9_0
12.45   - giflib==5.2.1=h80987f9_3
12.45   - git-lfs==2.13.3=hca03da5_0
12.45   - glog==0.5.0=hc377ac9_0
12.45   - gmp==6.2.1=hc377ac9_3
12.45   - gmpy2==2.1.2=py311h40f64dc_0
12.45   - google-auth==2.22.0=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - google-auth-oauthlib==0.5.2=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - grpc-cpp==1.48.2=h877324c_0
12.45   - grpcio==1.48.2=py311h877324c_0
12.45   - gtest==1.14.0=h48ca7d4_0
12.45   - h5py==3.9.0=py311hba6ad2f_0
12.45   - hdf5==1.12.1=h160e8cb_2
12.45   - huggingface_hub==0.17.3=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - icu==68.1=hc377ac9_0
12.45   - idna==3.4=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - importlib-metadata==6.0.0=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - jinja2==3.1.2=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - jpeg==9e=h80987f9_1
12.45   - keras==2.12.0=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - krb5==1.20.1=h8380606_1
12.45   - libboost==1.73.0=h49e8a49_12
12.45   - libbrotlicommon==1.0.9=h1a28f6b_7
12.45   - libbrotlidec==1.0.9=h1a28f6b_7
12.45   - libbrotlienc==1.0.9=h1a28f6b_7
12.45   - libcurl==8.2.1=h0f1d93c_0
12.45   - libcxx==16.0.6=h4653b0c_0
12.45   - libedit==3.1.20221030=h80987f9_0
12.45   - libev==4.33=h1a28f6b_1
12.45   - libevent==2.1.12=hf27765b_0
12.45   - libffi==3.4.4=hca03da5_0
12.45   - libgfortran==5.0.0=11_3_0_hca03da5_28
12.45   - libgfortran5==11.3.0=h009349e_28
12.45   - libiconv==1.16=h1a28f6b_2
12.45   - libnghttp2==1.52.0=h10c0552_1
12.45   - libopenblas==0.3.21=h269037a_0
12.45   - libpng==1.6.39=h80987f9_0
12.45   - libprotobuf==3.20.3=h514c7bf_0
12.45   - libsqlite==3.44.2=h091b4b1_0
12.45   - libssh2==1.10.0=h449679c_2
12.45   - libthrift==0.15.0=h169de6a_2
12.45   - libuv==1.44.2=h80987f9_0
12.45   - libzlib==1.2.13=h53f4e23_5
12.45   - llvm-openmp==17.0.6=hcd81f8e_0
12.45   - lz4-c==1.9.4=h313beb8_0
12.45   - markdown==3.4.1=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - markupsafe==2.1.1=py311h80987f9_0
12.45   - mpc==1.1.0=h8c48613_1
12.45   - mpfr==4.0.2=h695f6f0_1
12.45   - mpmath==1.3.0=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - multidict==6.0.2=py311h80987f9_0
12.45   - multiprocess==0.70.14=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - ncurses==6.4=h313beb8_0
12.45   - networkx==3.1=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - ninja==1.10.2=hca03da5_5
12.45   - ninja-base==1.10.2=h525c30c_5
12.45   - nltk==3.8.1=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - numexpr==2.8.7=py311h6dc990b_0
12.45   - numpy==1.23.5=py311hb2c0538_0
12.45   - numpy-base==1.23.5=py311h9eb1c70_0
12.45   - oauthlib==3.2.2=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - openssl==1.1.1w=h1a28f6b_0
12.45   - orc==1.7.4=hdca1487_1
12.45   - packaging==23.1=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - pandas==2.1.4=py311h7aedaa7_0
12.45   - pip==23.3=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - protobuf==3.20.3=py311h313beb8_0
12.45   - pyarrow==11.0.0=py311h7575258_1
12.45   - pydantic-core==2.14.5=py311h94f323b_0
12.45   - pyjwt==2.4.0=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - pyopenssl==23.2.0=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - pysocks==1.7.1=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - python==3.11.0=hf452327_1_cpython
12.45   - python-xxhash==2.0.2=py311h80987f9_1
12.45   - pytorch==2.1.0=gpu_mps_py311hf322ab5_100
12.45   - pytz==2023.3.post1=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - pyyaml==6.0.1=py311h80987f9_0
12.45   - re2==2022.04.01=hc377ac9_0
12.45   - readline==8.2=h1a28f6b_0
12.45   - regex==2023.10.3=py311h80987f9_0
12.45   - requests==2.31.0=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - safetensors==0.4.0=py311h62f922a_0
12.45   - scikit-learn==1.3.2=py311ha25ca4d_2
12.45   - scipy==1.11.3=py311hc76d9b0_0
12.45   - sentencepiece==0.1.99=py311h48ca7d4_0
12.45   - setuptools==68.0.0=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - sleef==3.5.1=h80987f9_2
12.45   - snappy==1.1.9=hc377ac9_0
12.45   - sqlite==3.41.2=h80987f9_0
12.45   - sympy==1.11.1=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - tensorboard==2.12.1=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - tensorboard-data-server==0.7.0=py311ha6e5c4f_0
12.45   - tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.1=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - tensorflow==2.12.0=eigen_py311h689d69b_0
12.45   - tensorflow-base==2.12.0=eigen_py311h0a52ebb_0
12.45   - tensorflow-estimator==2.12.0=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - termcolor==2.1.0=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - tk==8.6.12=hb8d0fd4_0
12.45   - tokenizers==0.13.2=py311h3dd52b7_1
12.45   - tqdm==4.65.0=py311hb6e6a13_0
12.45   - transformers==4.32.1=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - urllib3==1.26.18=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - utf8proc==2.6.1=h1a28f6b_0
12.45   - uvicorn==0.24.0.post1=py311h267d04e_0
12.45   - werkzeug==2.2.3=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - wrapt==1.14.1=py311h80987f9_0
12.45   - xxhash==0.8.0=h1a28f6b_3
12.45   - xz==5.4.2=h80987f9_0
12.45   - yaml==0.2.5=h1a28f6b_0
12.45   - yarl==1.8.1=py311h80987f9_0
12.45   - zipp==3.11.0=py311hca03da5_0
12.45   - zlib==1.2.13=h53f4e23_5
12.45   - zstd==1.5.5=hd90d995_0
12.45 
12.45 Current channels:
12.45 
12.45   - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-aarch64
12.45   - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-aarch64
12.45   - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-aarch64
12.45 
12.45 To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
12.45 looking for, navigate to
12.45 
12.45     https://anaconda.org
12.45 
12.45 and use the search bar at the top of the page.
12.45 
12.45 
------
dockerfile:13
--------------------
  11 |     
  12 |     # Create Conda environment based on the environment.yml file
  13 | >>> RUN conda env create -f /code/environment.yml
  14 |     
  15 |     # Activate the Conda environment
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c conda env create -f /code/environment.yml" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

to be sure the yaml file is actually working on my local machine (macbook pro m1 arm64), i tried to build the env again, which worked successfully. I'm probably missing something, can you help me  please?

Comment: This is likely an osx vs linux arch issue - the hashes, such as `hc377ac9_0` for abseil-cpp are visible under `osx-arm64`, and not under `linux-aarch64` - you probably have to fix up your environment file to install conda packages for the appropriate architecture.

Comment: To add to what Anya said: you can checkout available packages and their compatible architecture on the anaconda site here: https://anaconda.org/